# C# Parse Json - System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Tags: c#, json, parsing, google-translate

I'm using the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json library

This doesn't Work

```
public class Detections
            {
                [DataContract]
                public class RootObject
                {
                    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
                    public DataObject Data { get; set; }
                }

                [DataContract]
                public class DataObject
                {
                    [DataMember(Name = "detections")]
                    public List<Detection> Detections { get; set; }
                }

                [DataContract]
                public class Detection
                {
                    [DataMember(Name = "language")]
                    public string Language { get; set; }
                    [DataMember(Name = "isReliable")]
                    public string IsReliable { get; set; }
                    [DataMember(Name = "confidence")]
                    public string Confidence { get; set; }
                }
            }
```

So how should I parse this

```
{
     "data": {
      "detections": [
       [
        {
         "language": "tr",
         "isReliable": false,
         "confidence": 0.086520955
        }
       ]
      ]
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clearify what you mean by "dont work"? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I'm not sure how picky the Json serializer is, have you tried things like using bool for isReliable instead of string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is occurring for two reasons.

1) Your nested classes needed to be removed from within the Detections class.

2) The JSON contains a multi-dimensional array for the detections member where I assume it needs to be single.

I have tested the code detailed below it works fine.

```
//Classes

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public DataObject Data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "detections")]
    public List<Detection> Detections { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Detection
{
    [DataMember(Name = "language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "isReliable")]
    public string IsReliable { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "confidence")]
    public string Confidence { get; set; }
}

//Code to deserialize

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
var json = "{\"data\": {\"detections\": [{\"language\": \"tr\",\"isReliable\": false,\"confidence\": 0.086520955}]}}";
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
var rootObject = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
stream.Close();
```

I Hope this helps you.

Comment: Please note that his json data differs from the data used in your example. "Detections" has double [ [ infront of it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except that `Detections` is a collection of collections. I don't know why it is that way but it works for me.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "detections")]
    public List<List<Detection>> Detections { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your json "Detection" is a list of lists. Please note that the answer from jdavies does not recognize this.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataObject
{
[DataMember(Name = "detections")]
public List<List<Detection>> Detections { get; set; }
}
```